# java script to transform json data

Tags: javascript, arrays

my survey output is like
{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"1","d":"0","e":"please improve","Id":"789"} when it reaches the jsp, and i would like to change 0 to good, 1 to bad and 2 to ok, which are the outputs of a,b,c,d .how can we do it using foreach function.

Comment: thanks, can u give me an example.

Comment: no it s good. thank you

Comment: damn ... I thought you were working with an array, as you mentioned foreach ... sorry for misleading you

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var input = {"a":"1","b":"2","c":"1","d":"0","e":"please improve","Id":"789"};

var mapvals = {"0":"good", "1":"bad", "2":"ok"};

var newObject = Object.keys(input).reduce(function(previous, current) {
    previous[current] = mapvals[input[current]] || input[current];
    return previous;
}, {});

console.log(newObject);
```

Which gives:

```
{
  a: "bad",
  b: "ok",
  c: "bad",
  d: "good",
  e: "please improve",
  Id: "789"
}
```

You could do it manually with a `forEach` function if you really wanted... but I'll leave that to you.

Comment: @munch, I dont' know what you mean by "my input is a whole table". `${jsondata}` isn't valid javascript... so I can't even guess what you mean (database table? html table? javascript array of arrays?). Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

`foreach()` and `map()` only work on arrays, so they can't be used directly on your object.  You'll have to use the `keys()` or `entries()` functions first to get the fields in the object as an array.

Unfortunately `Object.entries()` currently only works in Firefox(*). However, as it happens, `keys()` produces simpler code anyway.

```js
var input = {"a":"1","b":"2","c":"1","d":"0","e":"please improve","Id":"789"};

var mapvals = {"0":"good", "1":"bad", "2":"ok"};

var output = {};
Object.keys(input).forEach(function(key) {
    output[key] = mapvals[input[key]] || input[key];
});

console.log(output);
```

(*) It's available in Chrome also, but only behind a configuration flag.

Comment: @NickGrealy I hope you don't mind... I borrowed your framework to show that it could be done a little simpler than your example.

Comment: it is  an json array.{"a":"0","b":"2","c":"0","d":"0","e":" ","id":"456"},{"a":"0","b":"0","c":"0","d":"0","e":"test","id":"123"},{"a":"0","b":"2","c":"0","d":"0","e":"please test ","id":"456"},{"a":"0","b":"2","c":"0","d":"0","e":" ","id":"456"},{"a":"0","b":"1","c":"1","d":"0","e":" ","id":"456"},{"a":"2","b":"2","c":"2","d":"2","e":" ","id":"789"},{"a":"1","b":"1","c":"1","d":"1","e":"survey ","id":"789"},{"a":"1","b":"1","c":"2","d":"2","e":"1234567","id":"789"},{"a":"0","b":"0","c":"0","d":"0","e":" ","id":"234"},

Comment: We can't be blamed if your real data is different from what you described in your question.  In any case, all you need to do is take what I've done for one object and apply it to each element in your array.

Answer (score 0):

you could convert the values when serializing the object. Before you send the json to the backend:

```
var data = {"a":"1","b":"2","c":"1","d":"0","e":"please improve","Id":"789"};
var mapvals = {"0":"good", "1":"bad", "2":"ok"};
var json = JSON.stringify(data, (key, value) => key && value in mapvals? mapvals[value]: value);
```

json:

```
{"a":"bad","b":"ok","c":"bad","d":"good","e":"please improve","Id":"789"}
```

you can also add further "filter" to only apply this logic to some keys

also works with more complex data, like the Array of items like that, that you mentioned.

```
var data = [
    {"a":"0","b":"2","c":"0","d":"0","e":" ","id":"456"},
    {"a":"0","b":"0","c":"0","d":"0","e":"test","i‌​d":"123"},{"a":"0","‌​b":"2","c":"0","d":"‌​0","e":"please test ","id":"456"},
    {"a":"0","b":"2","c":"0","d":"0","e":" ","id":"456"},
    {"a":"0","b":"1","c":"1","d":"0","e":" ","id":"456"},
    {"a":"2","b":"2","c":"2","d":"2","e":" ","id":"789"},
    {"a":"1","b":"1","c":"1","d":"1","e":"survey ","id":"789"},
    {"a":"1","b":"1","c":"2","d":"2","e":"1234567"‌​,"id":"789"},
    {"a":"0‌​","b":"0","c":"0","d‌​":"0","e":" ","id":"234"}
];
var mapvals = {"0":"good", "1":"bad", "2":"ok"};
var json = JSON.stringify(data, (key, value) => key && value in mapvals? mapvals[value]: value);
```

json:

```
[{"a":"good","b":"ok","c":"good","d":"good","e":" ","id":"456"},{"a":"good","b":"good","c":"good","d":"good","e":"test","id":"123"},{"a":"good","b":"ok","c":"good","d":"good","e":"please test ","id":"456"},{"a":"good","b":"ok","c":"good","d":"good","e":" ","id":"456"},{"a":"good","b":"bad","c":"bad","d":"good","e":" ","id":"456"},{"a":"ok","b":"ok","c":"ok","d":"ok","e":" ","id":"789"},{"a":"bad","b":"bad","c":"bad","d":"bad","e":"survey ","id":"789"},{"a":"bad","b":"bad","c":"ok","d":"ok","e":"1234567","id":"789"},{"a":"good","b":"good","c":"good","d":"good","e":" ","id":"234"}]
```

Comment: ITS not a n object, its an array

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` works with Arrays too. I've extended the Answer.

Comment: there is a small problem, JSON.stringify(data, (key, value) => key && value in mapvals? mapvals[value]: value); doesnt work in IE, any suggestion

Comment: @munch, IE doesn't support fat arrows; you should change that part.

Comment: sorry but can u make it IE acceptable, no matter what i do , its giving an error .. thanks in advance. and unfortunately IE is the default browser for users